# selecting dropdownlist item in IronPython

Tags: asp.net, ironpython

I want to select a particular item in a dropdownlist by value, in asp.net using IronPython. 
I found I can do it like this

```
listItem = ddl.Items.FindByValue(x)
if listItem != None: listItem.Selected = True
```

But I want to do it in one line

Comment: You could wrap the code in a function and then just call the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution I can think of that might work:

```
if ddl.Items.FindByValue(x):  ddl.Items.FindByValue(x).Selected = True
```

It is kinda redundant, but if you really want a one-liner I guess it will do.

There probably is a better solution.